# Fortran iso_c_binding standard: Error: Type mismatch in argument 'test_variable' at (1); passed INTEGER(8) to TYPE(c_ptr)

Tags: c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

This question is reproducible because if the below program is compiled the below error message is output. There's no typographical errors.

My real life program uses integer*8 variables and does not compile with this specific iso_c_binding patch, see below. My program works fine when the iso_c_binding package is not used.

With the iso_c_binding package in my program, I get the following error message:

Error: Type mismatch in argument 'test_variable' at (1); passed INTEGER(8) to TYPE(c_ptr)

I’ve created the below testcase from my program. My program cannot be published. The testcase demonstrates the error that I’m getting.

Question 1: How do you fix this? The following is what I would like if at all possible! The two structs in the test.c file actually exist in my program. The game function formal arguments also actually exist in my real world program. My program passes integer*8 variables to the game routine. Everything else besides these three things should be able to be modified.

Other Questions: Does the C code have to change? Not counting the iso_c_binding interface code, does the Fortran code have to change? What has to change?

Can iso_c_binding do this?

Thank you,

**File the_game.f:**

```
  module the_game

  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_int, c_float, c_ptr

  type, bind(c) :: myfloat
    real(c_float) :: float_tmp
  end type

  type, bind(c) :: myint
    integer(c_int) :: int_tmp
  end type

  interface
    function game(myint1, myfloat2) bind(c, name="game_")
        import :: c_int, c_ptr
        implicit none
        type(c_ptr) :: myint1
        type(c_ptr) :: myfloat2
        integer(c_int) :: game
    end function
  end interface

  end module the_game
```

**File main.f:**

```
   program main
     use the_game
     integer*8 test_variable
     integer*8 test_variable2
     integer ans

     ans=game (test_variable,test_variable2)
   end program main
```

**File test.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct myfloat 
{
   float float_tmp;
};

struct myint 
{
   int int_tmp;
};


int game_(myint1,myfloat2)
struct myint **myint1;
struct myfloat **myfloat2;
{/* The following shows how the code will eventually be used */
 /* after malloc etc. */
 /* printf ("(*myint1)->int_tmp = %d\n",(*myint1)->int_tmp); */
 /* printf ("(*myfloat2)->float_tmp = %f\n",(*myfloat2)->float_tmp); */
 /* (*myint1)->int_tmp = 1; */
 /* (*myfloat2)->float_tmp = 100.1; */
  return(0);
}
```

**Compilation:**

```
  gcc      -g -c test.c     -o test.o 
  gfortran -g -c the_game.f -o the_game.o
  gfortran -g -c main.f     -o main.o
  gfortran -g    main.o test.o   -o main.exe   -lgfortran
```

**Output:**

```
main.f:9.19:

         ans=game (test_variable,test_variable2)                        
                   1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'myint1' at (1); passed INTEGER(8) to TYPE(c_ptr)
```

Comment: Please repost the Fortran code in a code block, not a quotation block, so it doesn't mess up the formatting.

Comment: Your interface for `game` says `myint1` is a `type(c_ptr)`, so the compiler is complaining that you've given it an integer instead of a `type(c_ptr)`. It's not clear why you expect anything different, so please give more detail about what you think is going on,

Comment: @francescalus, Beware @giraffe has been posting this question and variations on it in Fortran Discourse.  S/He has been told more than once that `INTEGER*8` and `TYPE(c_ptr)` are different.

Comment: If the code you've presented is the actual code you're interested in, then the obvious solution is to change the types of `test_variable` and `test_variable2` in (the original) `main.f` to `TYPE(c_ptr)`.  With that change, all sources compile cleanly and link successfully for me, and the resulting program runs for me without emitting any diagnostics, exiting with status 0.  I'm inclined to guess that that's not the answer you're looking for, but in that case, you're probably asking the wrong question.

Comment: The problem with your alternative 1 is that it does not `use` the `iso_c_binding` module.  When I fix that, it compiles, links successfully with the C object, and the resulting program runs for me without emitting any diagnostic and exits with stratus 0.

Comment: The problem with your alternative 2 is that the C function assumes that the pointers it receives actually point to something, but the Fortran main program never makes that so.

Comment: Alternative 3 is again because that version of the Fortran `main` does not `use` the `iso_c_binding` module.  But it doesn't appear to be what you want anyway.  You are creating pointers to integers there, not pointers to structures.

Comment: What is the point of the C code receiving double pointers instead of single pointers?

Comment: My comment was deleted. Perhaps considered too chatty? Anyway, really, as I already mentioned under your other question, using this Fortran 2003 machinery to allocate memory this way is beyond bizarre, it completely WTF. Honestly, please do consider normal Fortran 90-like memory allocation using allocatable or pointer arrays. If for nothing else than for the simple reason that it is much simpler.

Comment: If you **really** have to allocate your memory in C, there are interfaces to standard C functions like `malloc`, `realloc` `free` and similar available and can be called easily.

Comment: Variant3: You must `use iso_c_binding`, that is also true for variant 1. Variant 4: because variable1 and 2 are neither pointer nor target, the message is quite clear about that. In Fortran, you can only make pointers to entities that are targets or pointers.

Comment: When you say "the actual code does use malloc", do you mean that the structures you are trying to pass around are dynamically allocated *in C*?  Your example code shows allocation *in Fortran*.  If they are allocated in C, then how is Fortran getting access to them?  The example code in your C `game_()` function does not appear to be doing anything appropriate for that purpose.

Comment: @giraffe, one of the biggest problems that we have had in trying to answer your question is that the code you are presenting seems not to be representative of what you actually want to do, and your explanations aren't doing much better.  How about you assume that everyone here knows both C and Fortran better than you do, and how about you do your best to answer the questions that are actually posed to you?  I assure you that we are asking because you are not conveying your requirements effectively.

Comment: For example, the example code in your `game_()` function seems to assume that that function will receive double pointers.  Is that because that function will allocate space and return pointers to the allocated space via the parameters?  Else, what ***is*** the point of the double pointers?  And if `game_()` is allocating space, are you expecting that the Fortran side will afterward be able to access the C structures in the allocated space?

Comment: ... and the Fortran side should be able to access the allocated memory as objects of, for example, type `type(myfloat)`?  Or maybe arrays of such objects?

Comment: If you are really desperate, just retrieve a `type(c_ptr)` and do `i  = transfer(p, i)` where `i` is an 8-byte integer.  At your own risk. Be aware that `integer*8` is not standard Fortran and `integer(c_intptr_t)` is more accurate and portable.

Comment: @giraffe, you seem to be having trouble understanding that using a variable of type `integer` to access an object that is *not* of the corresponding integer type is *wrong*.  It has always been wrong, in both Fortran and C, before, after, and irregardless of the ISO C binding.  That does not preclude the possibility that wrong code based on such a conflation might work or have worked with some combination of Fortran and C implementations, but that does not make it correct.  That your code does not compile now is just one manifestation. [...]

Comment: [...] Any proper solution involves fixing what is actually wrong, which seems to be the one thing you are fixated on *not* changing -- use of an `integer*8` or other integer on the Fortran side.  When you're ready to apply a correct fix, giving that up, one of the two alternatives presented in my answer is probably it.

Comment: @giraffe, I think this particular question has been discussed to death in these comments, as well as thoroughly answered.  We frown on modifying a question in any way that invalidates existing answers.  If the discussion and answer have inspired a *different* question then please feel free to post that *as* a different question.

Comment: @giraffe, as far as a link, the official standards documents are not available for free, but you can read [a late committee draft of Fortran 2008](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf).  You might want to pay particular attention to paragraphs 12.5.2.4/2 ("The dummy argument shall be type compatible with the actual argument. [...]") and 4.3.1.3/4 ("A nonpolymorphic entity is type compatible only with entities of the same declared type. [...]").

Comment: @giraffe a wrong program can do anything, including even what its author intended.  If it does happen to do what its author intended, that doesn't make it right.  And note well that it is not the `iso_c_binding` module that makes the program wrong.  Rather, `iso_c_binding` creates a *possibility* to write it in a way that is correct relative to the language standard, which possibility did not previously exist.

Comment: No, @giraffe, because nobody said that either of those was (inherently) wrong.  What is wrong is associating either one with an argument of any integer type.  I speculated in my answer that the double pointer might not be what you really wanted, but I offered a Fortran-side alternative for each one, and even some commentary about circumstances in which the double-pointer version might make sense.

Comment: @giraffe, you seem to be operating under the misapprehension that this is a discussion or an iterative problem-solving process.  It is not, at least not from the SO perspective.  At SO, you ask a question, and then, often, you get one or more answers.  There may be requests for clarification or similar minor chatter about both questions and answers, but we are not your consultants, nor otherwise committed to an extended engagement on a given question.  If you have followup questions then ask them as their own questions.

Answer (score 1):

> Error: Type mismatch in argument 'test_variable' at (1); passed INTEGER(8) to TYPE(c_ptr)

Yes, `INTEGER(8)` is a different type from `TYPE(c_ptr)`.  Associating an argument of the former type with a subprogram parameter of the latter type is not allowed.

> Question 1: How do you fix this? The following is what I would like if
> at all possible! The two structs in the test.c file actually exist in
> my program.

There aren't any struct objects in test.c.  There are two structure *type* declarations, but no objects of those types in evidence.  This is consequential, because it is unclear where you expect any such objects actually to be defined, or by whom allocated.

> The game function formal arguments also actually exist in
> my real world program.

Of course the formal arguments to the `game_()` function exist.  Their declarations in the definition of that function are that is required for that.  But perhaps you're talking about the objects to which they point?

> My program passes integer*8 variables to the
> game routine.

Probably not without your compiler at least complaining.  The parameters are pointers, not integers.  I would expect a C compiler to emit an analogous complaint when processing an attempt to call the `game_()` function in C with arguments that were integers of any size.  C pointers are not integers, neither in C nor in Fortran.

> Everything else besides these three things should be
> able to be modified.

There's been a lot of noise and lack of clarity here, but I think what you actually want is for

- the Fortran code to define instances of two structure types, and
- to pass pointers to those objects as arguments to the C `game_()` function,
- so that the latter can access their members.

You have put a lot of attention on `integer*8` and `integer(8)` (which are not necessarily the same thing), when these just aren't the right tools for the job.  I suspect that you have also engaged one more level of indirection on the C side than is needed or helpful.

Since you're using the GNU compiler suite, you should consider reading [its documentation of the Fortran / C interoperability features](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Interoperability-with-C.html#Interoperability-with-C), which is not half bad.

You have at least these considerations to deal with:

- declaring Fortran derived types that are interoperable with your C structure types
- defining your C function with parameter types best suited to your actual needs
- defining an appropriate interoperable interface to your C function
- calling the C function correctly from Fortran.

I think you're actually making it harder than it needs to be on both sides.

You do seem to have the interoperable type declarations sorted out.

The C function declaration appears to be another story.  I don't see any plausible reason why you would want to receive double pointers to the structures, and the result is probably not what you think.  Whether you expect the Fortran code to associate a single structure with each parameter or an array of them, you probably want the C side to declare the parameters as single pointers.  Note also that although you *can* use a C function name with a trailing underscore, you are not required to do.  Just specify whatever name you choose in the Fortran interface to it.

Example:

**test.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct myfloat {
   float float_tmp;
};

struct myint {
   int int_tmp;
};

int game_(struct myint *myint1, struct myfloat *myfloat2) {
    puts("C says:");
    printf ("myint1->int_tmp = %d\n", myint1->int_tmp);
    printf ("myfloat2->float_tmp = %f\n", myfloat2->float_tmp);

    myint1->int_tmp = 1;
    myfloat2->float_tmp = 2.0;

    return 0;
}
```

Note in particular that only one level of indirection is used for the arguments.

The Fortran interface is also pretty straightforward:

**the_game.f90**

```
module the_game

  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_int, c_float, c_ptr

  type, bind(c) :: myfloat
    real(c_float) :: float_tmp
  end type

  type, bind(c) :: myint
    integer(c_int) :: int_tmp
  end type

  interface
    function game(myint1, myfloat2) bind(c, name="game_")
        import :: c_int, myfloat, myint
        implicit none
        type(myint) :: myint1      ! not a pointer!
        type(myfloat) :: myfloat2  ! not a pointer!
        integer(c_int) :: game
    end function
  end interface

end module the_game
```

Note that the function parameters are not defined as pointers.  Fortran will pass pointers by default because its default subprogram invocation semantics use (approximately) pass by reference.  It's mainly when you want to pass by value (as you often might do, because those are C's semantics) that you need to need to do anything special in the declared interface.

Having that in hand, it's not hard to call it from Fortran.  Example:

**main.f90**

```
program main

use the_game

type(myint) :: test_variable
type(myfloat) :: test_variable2
integer ans

test_variable%int_tmp = 7
test_variable2%float_tmp = 3.14

ans = game(test_variable,test_variable2)

write(*, *)
write(*, *) 'Fortran says:'
write(*, *) 'Result = ', ans, '; my int = ', test_variable%int_tmp,     &
                              '; my_float = ', test_variable2%float_tmp

end program main
```

Note that there is neither any `c_ptr` nor any corresponding `integer` in the Fortran code that calls the C function.  The Fortran side just works in terms of the (interoperable) Fortran derived types.  And here's the output, showing that both sides are accessing the same objects:

> ```
> $ ./main.exe 
> C says:
> myint1->int_tmp = 7
> myfloat2->float_tmp = 3.140000
>
>  Fortran says:
>  Result =            0 ; my int =            1 ; my_float =    2.00000000
> ```

---

**ALTERNATIVELY**

Later comments suggest that perhaps you intend to use the parameters to `game_()` to pass C pointers back to the Fortran caller, perhaps pointers to dynamically allocated space.  That, too, can be accommodated, and in that case you do have to deal with `c_ptr`, because that's what C will emit.  But you do have to take care with level of indirection -- Fortran will pass an object of type `c_ptr` to C *by reference*, which C will receive as a double pointer.

Once it gets the C pointer values back, Fortran will use the `c_f_pointer()` subroutine to associate appropriately typed Fortran pointers with the allocated space, through which it can access the contents.  Example:

**alttest.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct myfloat {
   float float_tmp;
};

struct myint {
   int int_tmp;
};

int game_(struct myint **myint1, struct myfloat **myfloat2) {
    *myint1 = malloc(sizeof(**myint1));
    *myfloat2 = malloc(sizeof(**myfloat2));

    if (!*myint1 || !*myfloat2) {
        return -1;
    }

    (*myint1)->int_tmp = 1;
    (*myfloat2)->float_tmp = 2.0;

    return 0;
}
```

**the_game_alt.f90**

```
module the_game_alt

  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_int, c_float, c_ptr

  type, bind(c) :: myfloat
    real(c_float) :: float_tmp
  end type

  type, bind(c) :: myint
    integer(c_int) :: int_tmp
  end type

  interface
    function game(myint1_p, myfloat2_p) bind(c, name="game_")
        import :: c_int, c_ptr
        implicit none
        type(c_ptr), intent(out) :: myint1_p
  nd in this case you do have to deal with `c_ptr`      type(c_ptr), intent(out) :: myfloat2_p
        integer(c_int) :: game
    end function
  end interface

end module the_game_alt
```

**altmain.f90**

```
program main

use the_game_alt
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding

type(myint), pointer :: intvar
type(myfloat), pointer :: floatvar
type(c_ptr) :: myint_ptr, myfloat_ptr
integer ans


ans = game(myint_ptr, myfloat_ptr)
if (ans .ne. 0) then
    write(*, *) 'error: C returned ', ans
else
    call c_f_pointer(myint_ptr, intvar)
    call c_f_pointer(myfloat_ptr, floatvar)

    write(*, *)
    write(*, *) 'Fortran says:'
    write(*, *) 'Result = ', ans, '; my int = ', intvar%int_tmp, &
                                  '; my_float = ', floatvar%float_tmp
end if
end program main
```

Program output:

> ```
> $ ./altmain.exe 
>
>  Fortran says:
>  Result =            0 ; my int =            1 ; my_float =    2.00000000
> ```

---

**NOTE WELL**:

It remains unclear what you actually want to do.  It may be that something different from either of the above approaches is in fact required.